# How to run a multiple AND condition in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

That seems an awful noob question, and it is, but I can't figure it out, how to run a multiple "if" AND condition in AngularJS ?

I thought it was like Javascript, using two "&&", and that what I saw on the internet. But if you take a look on the code below, this doesn't work. With only one condition I'm able to enter in the if, but at the point I add a &&, it doesn't work. No error, just doesn't enter in my condition even if I'm sure of my variables.

```js
// THESE THREE VARIABLES WORK
console.log("Return false", $scope.h);
console.log("Return true", $scope.g);
console.log("Return false", $scope.a);


// I TRIED THIS 
if (($scope.g === true) && ($scope.h === false) && ($scope.a === false)) {
  console.log("I'm in !");
}

// THIS 
if ($scope.g === true && $scope.h === false && $scope.a === false) {
  console.log("I'm in !");
}

// AND THIS
if ($scope.g && !$scope.h && !$scope.a) {
  console.log("I'm in !");
}

// THIS IS WORKING BUT I DON'T WANT THAT
if ($scope.g === true) {
  console.log("I'm in !");
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure the values in your `$scope` are actually [booleans](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) and not [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). The often can look similar when output in the console.

Comment: I think that edit to add the snippet initialization probably obscures the issue - those variables can't be what the OP thinks they actually are, or this code would be working.

Comment: @George why did you remove the declariation of the variables and stopped the snippet being runnable? Roolling back (maybe you did it by accident)

Comment: @George but on the other hand demonstrates why we need a [mcve] to help them fix their problem. I think this is a VtC and move on personally.

Answer (score 2):

I just set `g`, `h` and `a` to the expected results of your `console.log`, and all the `if` are evaluated as `true`. It seems to work as expected:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
  
  $scope.h = false;
  $scope.g = true;
  $scope.a = false;
  
  console.log("Return false:", $scope.h);
  console.log("Return true:", $scope.g);
  console.log("Return false:", $scope.a);

  // I TRIED THIS 
  if(($scope.g === true) && ($scope.h === false) && ($scope.a === false)) {
    console.log("I'm in if 1!");
  }

  // THIS 
  if($scope.g === true && $scope.h === false && $scope.a === false) {
    console.log("I'm in if 2!");
  }

  // AND THIS
  if($scope.g && !$scope.h && !$scope.a) {
    console.log("I'm in if 3!");
  }

  // THIS IS WORKING BUT I DON'T WANT THAT
  if($scope.g === true) {
   console.log("I'm in if 4!");
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController"></div>
```